# Am I correctly determining whether the vectors are in the subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am supposed to use the following theorem:

THEOREM 4.2.1

If W is a set of one or more vectors in a vector space $V$,then $W$ is a
subspace of $V$ if and only if the following conditions are satisfied.

```
(a) If u and v are vectors in W, then u+v is in W.

(b) If k is a scalar and u is a vector in W, then ku is in W
```

to determine whether all vectors of the form $(a,0,0)$ are a subspace of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$

To show that all those vectors are closed under addition, can I do the following?

Let $W = all vectors of the form (a, 0, 0)$
. Let $u = (a_1, 0, 0)$ and let $v = (a_2, 0, 0)$ and let $a = a_1 + a_{2}$
Then $u+v$ is in $W$ because $u +v = (a, 0, 0)$.

I feel like I'm missing something in terms of the variable a. Is a just a variable that can represent any and all real numbers? If so, then the first component of every vector in W can be a real number, and the sum of 2 real numbers is itself a real number, so the first part of the theorem would be satisfied. What allows me to make the assumption that a can be any real number in one vector in W, but a different real number in another vector in W? Nothing in the question specifically defines a as being any real number. a is just given as a random variable and I just don't know how..powerful it is.

Sorry if this is a confusing question, I think I may be overthinking, but it is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When proving closure under vector addition, you need to show that when you take $u$ and $v$ and add them together, you don't create something that isn't in the set. So in particular, you need to make sure that the resulting vector "looks like" the starting vectors.

We know that if $u = (a_1, 0, 0)$ and $v = (a_2, 0, 0)$, where $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, then logically (although not as rigorous as some want), $a_1 + a_2$ is still a real number since adding any two real numbers gives you back a real number. We observe that $u + v = (a_1 + a_2, 0, 0)$ still has $0$'s in the other two spots and the first coordinate is still a real number. So since this vector still "looks like" a vector from $W$, then it must be in $W$.

What you did is fine, but you need to explain that $a_1 + a_2 = a \in \mathbb{R}$ to have a solid justification.